# How to not allow division by zero in C

Tags: c

I am currently using visual studio 2015. I was instructed to not allow division by zero. I am using a user defined function to calculate the results through arguments and return the result in the main function.

How do I not allow division by zero? Is this done in the user define function (getQuotient();)?

I am also using a user define function to ask the user for integers. Is it done there? Do I restrict the user from inputting a 0?

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You check to see if you're going to try to divide by 0 before actually dividing, and give an error message or something instead if so..

Comment: "Do I restrict the user from inputting a 0?" --> No. There   is not magic hand to prevent a user from typing in something.  Instead read the input and if 0, report the bad input and do not the division.

Comment: A good complementary read including some examples: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT33-C.+Ensure+that+division+and+remainder+operations+do+not+result+in+divide-by-zero+errors

Answer (score 2):

If your program receives two integers `a` and `b` from the user and you want to avoid division overflow when computing `a / b`, you must test these 2 cases:

- `b == 0` as division by zero has undefined behavior.
- on systems where integers are stored using two's complement representation, `a == INT_MIN && b == -1` causes a division overflow because the result does not fit in the type `int`. This has undefined behavior as well.

Both of the above cause early program termination on most current PC architectures.

Comment: Does the second check (at least the explanation of the reason) assume 2-complement representation?

Comment: @Yunnosch: yes it does. Given the terseness of the question, I did not see fit to expand on language lawyering considerations, but there is always a sharp eye watching :)

Comment: Good enough as a useful answer. It was just a clarification for us nitpickers. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of unclear as to what exactly what needs to be done. I assume you are expected to develop which would execute the basic calculator, with the restrictions on dividing by zero.

Here is the code where operands and operator is accepted from the user using separate functions. It also restricts the division operation from executing with ) as the divisor.

```
# include <stdio.h>

double acceptData();
char acceptChar();
int main() {

    char operator;
    double firstNumber,secondNumber;
    operator = acceptChar();
    firstNumber = acceptData();
    secondNumber = acceptData();

    switch(operator)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("%.1lf + %.1lf = %.1lf",firstNumber, secondNumber, firstNumber + secondNumber);
            break;

        case '-':
            printf("%.1lf - %.1lf = %.1lf",firstNumber, secondNumber, firstNumber - secondNumber);
            break;

        case '*':
            printf("%.1lf * %.1lf = %.1lf",firstNumber, secondNumber, firstNumber * secondNumber);
            break;

        case '/':
            if(secondNumber == 0.0) {
              printf("cannot divide by zero..\n");
              }
            else{
              printf("%.1lf / %.1lf = %.1lf",firstNumber, secondNumber, firstNumber / secondNumber);
              }
            break;

        // operator doesn't match any case constant (+, -, *, /)
        default:
            printf("Error! operator is not correct");
    }

    return 0;
}

double acceptData() {
    double Number;
    printf("Enter the operand: ");
    scanf("%lf",&Number);
    return Number;
}

char acceptChar() {
  char operator;
  printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *,): ");
    scanf("%c", &operator);
  return operator;
}
```